# Boot camp assistant gives "Windows support software could not be saved to selected drive" Error Installing Win 10 on MBP2015

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootcamp, windows

I'm new to mac and trying to install Windows 10 on my Macbook Pro with specs

Macbook Pro Retina Mid 2015
Using macOS Sierra 10.12.6

I'm tying to install Windows 10 with BCA. But all the time I get this error at the end.

“Windows support software could not be saved to selected drive. An error occurred while saving the Windows support Software”.

My Macbook saves the Windows support software and windows ISO somewhere inside the mac-OS system so I don't need flash drive. And BCA don't give me the flash drive and download support software options. It asks for Windows ISO and then partition the drive and then goes straight for the downloading of Window Support Software.

Another problem is each time I get this error, BCA downloads all the Windows Support Software again. Which takes time and data (I'm using WiFi-connection speed 350kb/s).

I have also tried manually installing Windows 10 But that gives me this error while selecting the target window partition that I have created using Disk Utility.

[image: this is screenshot of my all partitions]

[image: Here when I select the partition, I got this error]

The output from the command `diskutil list` is given below.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                    TYPE NAME              SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:   GUID_partition_scheme                  *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                     EFI EFI               209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:               Apple_HFS Macintosh HD      499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:              Apple_Boot                   650.0 MB   disk0s4
```

So, anyone please help me to solve this. I've spent last week searching on internet but nothing works.

Thanks

Comment: You have not provided enough information to determine why Windows will not install using the Boot Camp Assistant. The manual installation failed for the exact reason given. When you manually partitioned your drive, the partitioning tools inadvertently made entries in the MBR table. Have you been able to use the Boot Camp Assistant to just download the Windows Support Software? Do you know how to?

Comment: When using the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows, you have failed. At this point, open a Terminal application window and enter the command `diskutil list`. Post the output to your question. This will help determine why you have failed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks.
Yeah, thats the problem that the error itself does not provide enough information. Even not enough to figure out the why error comes.
Yes, I've been able to download only Window Support Software.
Open the BCA.
In the menu bar, Select Action and then Select Download Window Support Software.

Comment: Ok I'll post the output of the diskutil list

Comment: @DavidAnderson What information do you need to determine why error occurs?

Comment: I am trying to determine the partitioning used to install macOS. Did you use a single JHFS+ volume, Core Storage or APFS. I also want to know if you have partitions beyond the 4 shown in the images you posted. Also, there is no such version 10.11.06 of Sierra.

Comment: The Boot Camp Assistant will only install Windows if your computer is configured a certain way. Most likely your computer is not configured this way. Since you have the Windows Support Software, you can install Windows without the use the Boot Camp Assistant. In order for me to post an answer, I need to decide whether you should or should not be using the Boot Camp Assistant. Should I just assume you do not what to use the Boot Camp Assistant?

Comment: I'm new to mac so I don't know a lot about it. I was using El Captian then I upgraded to High Sierra but I decided to go to Sierra. Then I clean installed Sierra. I was using Windows 10 with boot camp on El Captian(I tried 2 times installing windows 10 on El Captian ) first time I get the error we are discussing but second time I succeeded. But on Sierra I'm always getting this error.

Comment: this is output of the command diskutil list

    diskutil list
    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
     1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.4 GB   disk0s2
     3:                 Apple_Boot                         650.0 MB   disk0s4

Comment: And I have tried installing Windows 10 without BCA with USB. But that way I need to convert MBR partition into GPT. And way I'll loose all my data. That is why I want to use bootcamp assistant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will address your attempt to manually install Windows 10 without the use of the Boot Camp Assistant. Here are some points.

- You are using Sierra. This is good in the sense that High Sierra has introduced APFS. This has caused some problems that you will be avoiding.
- You created a bootable USB installer. I do not know how you did this, but you do have to copy the Windows Support software to this USB flash drive before installing Windows. If you can not do this, let me know.
- I appears you created a FAT formatted fourth partition labelled "BOOTCAMP". I do not know what procedure you used do accomplish this. However, a FAT format for this partition caused the Windows installer to incorrectly believe you have a MBR partitioning scheme. You should have formatted this partition as "Mac OS Extend (Journaled)".
- When the Windows installer asks "Where to install Windows?", you should proceed as follows. First, delete the fourth partition. Next, select the free space. Finally, select "Next" to continue.

Comment: Yahoooo.. just 1 mint ago I solved it. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I did it using Bootcamp but as soon as boot camp partitions the drive I have force restart my mac and booom I went to the boot mode and installed windows and I do have the support drivers.. thanks btw